# Loan Execution using sharkysdk

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter

I was hoping to get some help here we were able to integrate wallet to our  platform and we are close to integrating sharky sdk so users can take loans from us, but we had an error in the last step and I was wondering if it is from us or the package. the fetch loan, orderbook ... working smoothly except for this part

```
// Execute the instruction
try {
  const { takenLoan, sig } = await loan.take({
    program,
    nftMintPubKey: new PublicKey(options.collateralMint),
    nftListIndex,
    skipFreezingCollateral: !isFreezable,
  });

  console.log(
    `Loan taken! Its pubkey is: ${takenLoan.pubKey.toString()}; tx sig: ${sig}`,
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.error(`Error taking loan (sig: ${e.sig})`, e);
}
```